# Why are the form params not getting passed on to the end point through the apache handler?

Tags: apache, perl

I added this
PerlAccessHandler MyApache::TokenCheck

to /etc/httpd/conf.d/perl.conf

This the handler in TokenCheck.pm

```
sub handler {
    my $r  = shift;
    my $cookie = CGI::Cookie->fetch($r);
    my %cookies = map { split /=/, $_, 2 } split /; /, $cookie->{'sessionID'};
    my $sessionID = $cookies{'sessionID'};

    if( $r->method eq 'POST' ) {

my $cgi = CGI->new($r);
my $token = $cgi->param('csfr_token');

        my $ac = MyPkg::CheckSess->new;
        if( !$ac->validSessionWithToken($sessionID, $token) ) {
            # redirect or something
            return Apache2::Const::FORBIDDEN;
        }

        return Apache2::Const::OK;
    } else {
        if ($sessionID) {
            my $checker = new MyPkg::CheckSess();
            if ($checker->validSessionID($sessionID)) {
                return Apache2::Const::OK;
            } else {
                return Apache2::Const::FORBIDDEN;
            }
        } else {
            return Apache2::Const::FORBIDDEN;
        }
    } # end else
}
```

The problem I'm running into is when I instantiate the CGI object with $r (Apache2::RequestRec)
I get the form data but it's not passing those form variables on to the end point.

I've also tried this read_post from https://metacpan.org/dist/mod_perl/view/docs/api/Apache2/RequestRec.pod#input_filters
with the same result.

With out the handler the form works fine. If I don't try and read the cgi params in the handler and remove this block the params are passed to the end point.

```
        if( !$ac->validSessionWithToken($sessionID, $token) ) {
              ...
        }
```

Is there a reason they wouldn't be getting passed along?

Comment: *"...and remove this block the params are passed..."* : So it returns `Apache2::Const::FORBIDDEN;` if the block is there?

Comment: Try my $apr = Apache2::Request->new( $r );
my @args = $apr->param;    or   my $cgi = CGI->new($r->args());

Comment: my $apr = Apache2::Request->new( $r );  causes 502 bad gateway.